# vnc connection only possible via localhost

Tags: vncserver

I started `vncserver :3` and can only connect via an `ssh -L 5903:localhost:5903 machine42` connection coupled with `vncviewer localhost::5903`. But a direct connection with `vncviewer astro101:3` hangs (last message: `DecodeManager: Creating 4 decoder thread(s))`.

Using the option `-localhost` no as proposed in https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/398905/vnc-server-only-listening-for-connections-from-localhost, returns `Unrecognized option: no`.

Has the syntax changed? So how are direct connections possible?